# Matrix inversion in the smoothing splines

Tags: splines, smoothing

The question is about the matrix inversion in the smoothing splines.

Given observations (y1, x1), ..., (yn, xn) and a choice of $\lambda \ge 0$, the smoothing spline estimator, $\hat{f}_{\lambda}$ is defined by
$$
\hat{f}_{\lambda} = argmin~\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - f(x_i))^2 + \lambda \int f''(t)^2 dt
$$
It is well-known that the solution to the above optimization problem is a natural cubic spline with knots at the unique values of x.

Given the natural spline basis functions {$h_1, ..., h_n$}, we have $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}h_j(x)\theta_j$ and $H_{n \times n} = {h_j(x_i)}_{i,j=1}^n$. Solving the $\hat{f}_{\lambda}$ is equivalent to solve the problem
$$
argmin_{\theta \in R^n} ||y - H\theta||_2^2 + \lambda \theta^T\Omega\theta,
$$
where the penalty matrix $\Omega$ has entries $\Omega_{jk} = \int h_j''(x)h_k''(x)dx$.

This is a generalized Ridge regression problem, and the solution is
$$
\hat{\theta} = (H^TH + \lambda \Omega)^{-1}H^TY
$$

Suppose I use the natural cubic spline to compute $H$ and $\Omega$. When I put knots at each distinct x values, what to do if $H^TH + \lambda \Omega$ is singular?

Note this is different from another question in another poster. In that question it did not address the placement of knots issue.

Comment: Much easier is to use fewer knots, avoid penalization, and to use ordinary fitting and confidence interval methods with small matrices.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks for the quick response. This sounds a nice idea, but in this case, I want to study the smoothing spline so that I wanna put knots at each distinct x value.

Comment: Just make sure the need for research does not override the need to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Sure, Dr. Harrell, thanks for the suggestion. It is out of interest and I did not come up such a question until I read materials about spline again recently, but could not find a reasonable answer by myself.

Comment: @Sycorax Under that poster, I made comments and asked this question because the two questions are at different conditions

Comment: Increasing $\lambda$ infinitesimally will remove the singularity.  The duplicate shows why this is so.